What do I wrong with crc16-x25 calculation in python?
I have this code in python 3 to calculate CRC16-X25:
import crcmod


# CRC function using the CRC-16-CCITT standard
crc16 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x11021, initCrc=0xFFFF, xorOut=0xFFFF, rev=True)

def calculate_crc(data):
    return crc16(data)

hex_data = '010e00180510100b1b020100000100ff'
    
# Convert the hex string to bytes
binary_data = bytes.fromhex(hex_data)

# Calculate the CRC
crc_value = calculate_crc(binary_data)

# Print the CRC value in hexadecimal format
print(f'CRC value: {crc_value:04X}')

I am not sure if rev should be True or False, so anyway I try both.
But in none of the case I could get the expected answer which 0xAF47.
However when I calculate with this online tool calculate crc16-x25,
in CRC-16/X-25 it does give 0xAF47.

So, what is wrong with my python code?
BTW: crcmod.predefined.Crc('x-25') DO gives the expected result. What is wrong in mkCrcFun(0x11021, initCrc=0xFFFF, xorOut=0xFFFF, rev=True)?

The screenshot with the correct result shows 0x1021, your code contains 0x11021, is that a typo and should be 0x1021?

in X-25 the poly must be 0x1021, yes. However, mkCrcFun gives
ValueError: The degree of the polynomial must be 8, 16, 24, 32 or 64
error, when passing 0x1021.
And from internet I see that they give 0x11021, putting 1 at principal. I did not get why.

I saw that, xorOut=0x0000, rev=True  gives the same result. But this does not match with X-25. So, there is some thing rare with mkCrcFun. It does some thing "not expected" by itself.

@mkrieger1 No. The 0x11021 has the x^16 term included. That is needed, and is how crcmod knows the length of the CRC.

Use crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x11021, initCrc=0, xorOut=0xFFFF, rev=True). The initCrc parameter in mkCrcFun() is actually the exclusive-or of the init and xorout parameters you will see in other definitions, such as the one at https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat.crc-16-ibm-sdlc .
